# Advent of Code 2017 - day 8 solution

Tags: haskell

Today I solved the [Advent of Code - Day 8 challenge](http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/8) in Haskell. Although the code runs fine and produces the correct results, I'm sure there are lots of improvements to be made, as I am a Haskell beginner.

#### The Challenge

The challenge is to build a "CPU" that can parse and execute instructions such as these:

```
a dec -186 if b != -2
a inc 585 if c >= 9
```

In the example above, `a`, `b` and `c` are registers. You don't know upfront what are the registers of your particular CPU, but it is specified that all registers start with the value 0. So I modeled the whole thing as a `Data.Map String Int`, where the `String` represents the register name and the `Int` is the value.

The goal is to execute a number of such instructions on a new CPU (all registers having the value 0) and answer two questions:

- at the end, what is the maximum value stored in any register?
- what is the maximum value stored in a register during the entire process?

#### The Code

The full code with some tests is available [on Github](https://github.com/clupasq/aoc2017/blob/198ebb4aea49bb028e2f5cac10be2fd966f376f2/day8.hs), but I also pasted it below.

The thing that bothers me the most is how I handled the comparisons (`>=`, `==`, `!=`, etc.). It feels like there's a lot more code than needs to be, but don't know what the best solution for that is.

I could have mapped directly from the textual representation to the corresponding comparison functions (`>=`, `(==)`, `(/=)`, etc.).
But I modeled it like this because I wanted `Condition` and `Instruction` to derive `Eq` and `Show`, so I would be able to test the `parse` function, making equality assertions on instances of the `Instruction` type.

```
import Test.Hspec

import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe


type Register = String

data Comparison = Eq | Neq | Gt | Gte | Lt | Lte
                deriving (Eq, Show)

type Condition = (String, Comparison, Int)

data Instruction = Instruction Register Int Condition deriving (Eq, Show)

type CPU = M.Map Register Int

operation :: Comparison -> (Int -> Int -> Bool)
operation Eq  = (==)
operation Neq = (/=)
operation Gt  = (>)
operation Gte = (>=)
operation Lt  = (<)
operation Lte = (<=)


getVal :: CPU -> Register -> Int
getVal cpu r = fromMaybe 0 (M.lookup r cpu)

eval :: CPU -> Condition -> Bool
eval cpu (reg, comp, val) = op x val
  where op = operation comp
        x  = getVal cpu reg

exec :: CPU -> Instruction -> CPU
exec cpu (Instruction reg incr cond) | eval cpu cond = M.insert reg newval cpu
                                     | otherwise     = cpu
  where newval = getVal cpu reg + incr


parse :: String -> Instruction
parse str = Instruction reg incr (condreg, comp, val)
  where [reg, op, incdecstr, _, condreg, compstr, valstr] = words str
        incdec = read incdecstr
        incr   = if op == "dec" then (-incdec) else incdec
        val    = read valstr
        comp   = case compstr of
                      "==" -> Eq
                      "!=" -> Neq
                      ">"  -> Gt
                      ">=" -> Gte
                      "<"  -> Lt
                      "<=" -> Lte


highest :: CPU -> Int
highest cpu | M.null cpu = 0
            | otherwise  = maximum (M.elems cpu)


testCPU :: CPU
testCPU = M.fromList [("a", 10),
                      ("b", 20)]

getInstructions :: IO [Instruction]
getInstructions = do
  text <- readFile "input/day8.in"
  return $ map parse $ lines text

main = hspec $ do

  describe "CPU" $ do

    it "can parse instructions" $ do
      parse "d dec 461 if oiy <= 1" `shouldBe`
                          Instruction "d" (-461) ("oiy", Lte, 1)
      parse "eai inc 302 if pce >= -6317" `shouldBe`
                          Instruction "eai" 302 ("pce", Gte, (-6317))



    it "can read register values" $ do
      getVal testCPU "a" `shouldBe` 10
      getVal testCPU "b" `shouldBe` 20

    it "new registers start at 0" $ do
      getVal testCPU "unknown_reg" `shouldBe` 0

    it "can evaluate conditions" $ do
      eval testCPU ("a", Gt ,  9) `shouldBe` True
      eval testCPU ("a", Lt , 10) `shouldBe` False
      eval testCPU ("a", Lte, 10) `shouldBe` True
      eval testCPU ("a", Gte, 11) `shouldBe` False
      eval testCPU ("a", Gte, 10) `shouldBe` True
      eval testCPU ("a", Eq , 10) `shouldBe` True
      eval testCPU ("a", Neq, 10) `shouldBe` False
      eval testCPU ("b", Eq , 10) `shouldBe` False
      eval testCPU ("b", Neq, 10) `shouldBe` True

    describe "instruction execution" $ do

      it "registers are affected" $ do
        let instr = Instruction "a" 1 ("a", Gt, 0)
        let cpu'  = exec testCPU instr
        getVal cpu' "a" `shouldBe` 11

      it "registers are unchanged if condition is false" $ do
        let instr = Instruction "a" 1 ("a", Gt, 100000)
        let cpu'  = exec testCPU instr
        cpu' `shouldBe` testCPU


    describe "questions" $ do

      it "answers Q1" $ do
        instrs <- getInstructions
        let cpu = M.fromList []
        let finalState = foldl exec cpu instrs
        putStrLn "The highest value after all instructions:"
        print $ highest finalState

      it "answers Q2" $ do
        instrs <- getInstructions
        let cpu = M.fromList []
        let (_, maxval) = foldl step (cpu, 0) instrs
                            where step (c, oldmax) i = let c'     = exec c i
                                                           newmax = max oldmax (highest c')
                                                       in (c', newmax)
        putStrLn "The highest value ever:"
        print $ maxval
```

Comment: FWIW, it looks similar to my attempt https://github.com/ploeh/advent-of-code-2017/blob/master/Day08/Solution.hs

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thank you for your remark! BTW, I love your code, especially the parsing part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code itself looks fine, most of what I could say boils down to personal taste. So instead, I'm gonna take a step back and instead review the general way how you've decided to solve the problem - which is something I enjoy doing with Haskell code.

## Your flow of data

Your current `main` is just your testing code, so let's mentally change that to something like "read instructions from a file given as argument and execute those". (Note: this is not actual Haskell code)

What are the required steps to get from "some lines in a file" to "okay, what's the highest value in any register?"?

- `map parse . lines` to get a list of `Instruction`s
- `exec` to evaluate an `Instruction` given a `CPU`
- umm... `foldr (\` no wait, `exec (exe..` that can't be...

The problem I see is that there is no easy way to execute multiple instructions.
There's a small hotfix for that; swap the order of arguments for `exec` so you can do `exec firstInstruction $ exec secondInstruction $ exec thirdInstruction cpu`, but that's not that great either.

## What happens in a CPU stays in a CPU

You can't modify values inplace, there's always a copy that's returned back - that's the way Haskell works. But this is one of the cases where it certainly would be *nice* to manipulate values, your `CPU` that is.

### Introducing: State!

`State` (found in `Control.Monad.State`) is a handy monad to do exactly that - carry around a modifiable state on which you can perform many actions.

Let's think about what type of actions there actually are... honestly, there's just incrementing by some value. Easy enough then, let's write some code!

```
increaseRegisterBy :: Register -> Int -> State CPU ()
increaseRegisterBy reg incr = do
    cpu <- get
    cpu' = if reg `member` cpu
            then adjust (+ incr) reg cpu
            else insert reg incr cpu
    put cpu'
```

What that code does is:

- `get` the current State
- Increase the value in `reg` by `incr`
- `put` that new value as the state to be used in subsequent calls

So if you'd have a sequence of increments like `increaseRegisterBy "a" 255 >> increaseRegisterBy "a" (-255)`, you would get nothing out of it because those two cancel out. But you don't need to explicitly carry around the state, which is nice!

### Becoming a president, or: Running the state

When it comes to state, there's three functions to use which do different things:

- `runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)`
- `evalState :: State s a -> s -> a`
- `execState :: State s a -> s -> s`

The `State CPU ()` written earlier corresponds to the `State s a`. `s` is the type of the state to carry around, `a` is the result of the monadic action. Since we don't care about any results, we've put it as `()`. If you wanted to return the new value of the modified register, you'd have to set that signature as `Register -> Int -> State CPU Int`.

Since we only care about the final state (for now), we should use `execState`, which returns the final state when it's done working the registers.

### Autobots: Roll out! Transforming your `Instruction`

Now that we've got a way to run flashy `increaseRegisterBy`-actions, let's build those from your `Instruction`.

What we need is a function `runInstruction :: Instruction -> State CPU ()`, which takes in an instruction and runs that instruction on the current state. Or to be precise, which *returns a new function which then can be run using `execState`*. Trippy! What does that function need to do?

- Evaluate the condition
- If it's true, do the stuff
- If not, go home. Or just do nothing.

To put that into code:

```
runInstruction :: Instruction -> State CPU ()
runInstruction (Instruction reg incr cond) = do
    cpu <- get
    when (eval cpu cond) (increaseRegisterBy reg incr)
```

We `get` the current `CPU`, if `eval cpu cond` evaluates to true, we execute `increaseRegisterBy reg incr`. If not, nothing happens. That's why monads are awesome!

To glue it all together, executing a single instruction and getting the final CPU would look something like `execState (runInstruction yourInstruction) startCpu`.

### But wait, there's more (than one instruction)

Just like `when` or the `State` monad, there's another beauty hidden in `Control.Monad` to use: `sequence` (or it's forgetful brother `sequence_`).

```
sequence_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m ()
```

In more human terms, `sequence_` takes a list (which is something `Foldable`) of monadic actions (`m a`) and produces a single monadic action which does not return anything (`m ()`). The intermediate results of each action are lost, but since we don't have any, we don't care.

## Putting it all together

To be able to neatly execute a list of `Instruction`s, you'd have something like this:

```
executeInstructions :: [Instruction] -> CPU
executeInstructions is = execState (sequence_ $ map runInstruction is) M.empty

runInstruction :: Instruction -> State CPU ()
runInstruction (Instruction reg incr cond) = do
    cpu <- get
    when (eval cpu cond) (increaseRegisterBy reg incr)

increaseRegisterBy :: Register -> Int -> State CPU ()
increaseRegisterBy reg incr = do
    cpu <- get
    cpu' = if reg `member` cpu
            then adjust (+ incr) reg cpu
            else insert reg incr cpu
    put cpu'
```

## We want YOU to *monad*!

Your task, of course, would now be to actually implement your code using the `State` monad and all it's goodies from `Control.Monad`. Maybe take a look around that module, you might see interesting stuff.

As an exercise, you could rewrite the `runInstruction`-stuff to actually return something; maybe a tuple `(Register, Int)` to show which value was just supplied. You could then (by `group`ing and `maximum`ing) find out the maximum value for each register.

Oh, and try to swap that `main` for the "read instructions from a file given as argument and execute those"-thingy. `IO` is a monad too, after all!

### But what about the rest?

Looks fine by me, although I would have done the parsing using `megaparsec`, because I really like that library. It's overkill for something like this, though.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such an elaborate answer! It opens new pathways for me in the quest to understand this wonderful language. I will definitely play more with my solution and adjust it taking your suggestions into accout.